# How to get maven run parameters from inside a maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

There is a nice maven feature `--batch-mode`, which tells maven to run in non interactive mode.

Is there any way to get the value of this parameter from inside a maven plugin (in `MyMojo`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you can get the information from within a plugin via this:

```java
@Parameter (defaultValue = "${session}")
private MavenSession session;

...

if (session.getRequest().isInteractiveMode()) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'd like to add, that this code is not valid for `maven-core` 2.0. In such old version I had to use `session.getSettings().isInteractiveMode()`.              One more note - if I understand right, `maven-invoker-plugin` always run child processes in batch mode

Comment: I simply ignore Maven 2 cause [Maven 2 is End Of Life](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html). `maven-invoker-plugin` does not alway run in batch mode? What brings you to this assumption?

Comment: Didn't get your question about batch mode.
I just said that it seems to me that the plugin **always** run invoked poms in a batch-mode.
Isn't that true?